# Plot a point in a contour plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a contour plot in ggplot2 that I want to map one point to.

My contour plot looks like this:

```
v = ggplot(pts, aes(theta_1, theta_2, z = z))
v + stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..),bins=50) 
+ xlab(expression(Theta[1])) + ylab(expression(Theta[2]))
```

and I have a point that looks like this:

```
p = ggplot(ts,aes(x,y))
p + geom_point()
```

unfortunately the second overwrites the first.

Is there a way to get them to show up on the same plot, similar to MATLAB's "hold on;"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide the points directly to `geom_point()`:

```
set.seed(1000)
x = rnorm(1000)
g = ggplot(as.data.frame(x), aes(x = x))
g + stat_bin() + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = -1, y = 40), aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Greg. Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't work with <pre><code>stat_contour()</code></pre>. I get the error: <pre>Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found</pre> basically asking for a Z coordinate. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Since the contour is 3 dimensional, your point will need a z component in order that the plotting package knows where to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still of interest, but I think you just needed to save the updated v object then add the point to that, rather than create a new ggplot2 object. For example

```
v <- ggplot(pts, aes(theta_1, theta_2, z = z))
v <- v + stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..),bins=50) 
+ xlab(expression(Theta[1])) + ylab(expression(Theta[2]))
v <- v + geom_point(aes(x=ts$x, y=ts$y))
v # to display
```

ggplot2 is very good at adding layers incrementally, not all have to be based on the same dataset specified in the first ggplot call.